# Can an ideal rigid body be treated as hole in space?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, solid-mechanics

Wikipedia defines ideal [rigid body](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rigid_body) as

> "In physics, a ideal rigid body is an idealization of a solid body in which deformation is neglected. In other words, the distance between any two given points of a rigid body remains constant in time regardless of external forces exerted on it."

Basically you can't cut/mold/break it no matter what or how much force you exert. So it is an object that doesn't participate in natural cycle of things (non-renewable and non-recyclable), an entity would be an unique existence from all other physical objects.

**Question**
Since all the space acquired by the this body (equal to its volume) can't be interacted by anything, (light can't penetrate, electricity/heat will not conduct, magnetic field won't exert force);
Won't this be the case of having a hole in the space?

[image: black hole] [image]
Black hole is imagined as similar to other holes we see in life (an opening into or through something) so can this be called a anti-black hole or something? I'll leave the terminology to experts.

**Edit**
Intent of my question is if black holes can share attributes with ideal rigid body.

Comment: FWIW, an *ideal* anything is non-physical because it is *ideal* and so it seems to me that you're mixing contexts here; you seem to be conceptualizing  an *abstraction*, such as an ideal rigid body, as a physical *"entity that is an unique existence from all other physical objects"* and then go on to make a statement about said abstraction in the physical world.  Please try to clarify what you're asking or this question will probably be closed for being unclear.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri That is actually the intent of my question, what if black hole are in fact related to an ideal rigid body; edited my question to reflect this. About mixing contexts I'm not sure if this question belongs in physics or philosophy.

Comment: I don't see why an ideal rigid body could not conduct electricity? Rigidity just refers to elastic deformation, and is a macroscopic quantity. A rigid body can be heated, reflect light, ... your question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Since all the space acquired by the this body (equal to its volume) can't be interacted by anything, (light can't penetrate, electricity/heat will not conduct, magnetic field won't exert force);
>   Won't this be the case of having a hole in the space?

It depends on the definition of a "hole". One can make a mathematical model describing the topology of the rigid body and call it the description of a "hole". It is just a model for this specific idealized construct of yours.

> Black hole is imagined as similar to other holes we see in life (an opening into or through something)

Wrong concept.A black hole is a solution to a mathematical model , General Relativity, for specific values of boundary conditions. It depends on complicated theoretical  structures which describe well the universe in large dimensions and planetary dimensions ( GPS). Your rigid body is a simple geometrical model that has nothing to do with the complexities of a black hole model.

> ntent of my question is if black holes can share attributes with ideal rigid body.

No. If you take the trouble to [read the link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) you will see  what I am talking about.

> A black hole is a region of spacetime exhibiting such strong gravitational effects that nothing—not even particles and electromagnetic radiation such as light—can escape from inside it.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_hole) The theory of general relativity predicts that a sufficiently compact mass can deform spacetime to form a black hole.The boundary of the region from which no escape is possible is called the event horizon. Although crossing the event horizon has enormous effect on the fate of the object crossing it, it appears to have no locally detectable features. In many ways a black hole acts like *an ideal black body*, as it reflects no light

Your rigid body with no interactions is not a black body, so even this analogy would fail.